# Can we implement polyphase fft for N point even when filter coeffients length is 4N for example?

Tags: fft, polyphase

This paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10051908 tells that we can implement polyphase fft even when data length is less than filter coefficients length.

I am confused how can we implement the polyphase fft when i have limited data length and filter coefficients greater than data length as we need to achieve better resolution with polyphase fft

Can anyone explain how do we implement polyphase fft  in this case of data length being fixed but filter coefficients length is greater than data length?

Comment: Can you point to the exact statement or quote it here explicitly.

Comment: You can always zero pad data and/or filter coefficients to what you need. If the data is short, efficiency shouldn't be an issue and why would you use polyphase in the first place ?

Comment: @Hilmar : thanks for the reply, the reason for using polyphase is due to the increased spectral resolution it gives over windowing approach of fft. Suppose if we have to do 1024 point fft and say for getting higher resolution i design filter coefficients having sharp frequency response is having 4096 filter coefficients......how do i implement polyphase fft in this case....

Comment: @Irreducible : In the paper i mentioned below is the statement they have mentioned . The channelizer has decoupled the length of the window from the length of the data! This is the power of the channelizer [24], it allows us to reduce the effect of the windowing distortion down to the fundamental resolution of the R-point FFT. It would be of great help if you could go through the paper and see that what is mentioned there makes sense with respect to designing polyphase FFT when data length is limited. How can we do this for say 1024 point fft with 4096 filter coefficents